# How can I get Libre Office to stop storing my changes?

Tags: cache, libreoffice-writer, cut-and-paste

Apparently Libre Office is keeping old copies of my document in memory, because after systematically cutting a page at a time from a document (and pasting it into another one), the source document does not decrease in size, and after a couple of pages the cutting-and-pasting process becomes very slow.

I don't want it to keep any of my "cuttings" in memory. How can I tell it to cease and desist with the overly cautious caching?

### UPDATE

I have two general ideas for options that may need to be changed, but don't know what option of which screen will help me. Here's one possibility:

[image]

..and here's another:

[image]

...but I don't know which option needs to change, and to what value.

Comment: Do the settings under Options -> OpenOffice -> Memory look relevant?

Comment: Please see my update